# sapui5 component settings shown sometimes, sometimes undefined (same code)

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, sapui5

I want to use the same SAPUI5 component for different uses.

I want to differentiate between the uses with settings, as shown here

```
var oComponentContainer = new sap.ui.core.ComponentContainer( {
                    url : "resources/components/clientSelector",
                    name : "components.clientSelector",
                    id : "components.clientSelector",
                    propagateModel : true,
                    settings : {
                        bPopupView : true,
                        iOffset : $(document).height() - 300
                    }
                });
```

Sometimes when I console.log my component.oContainer, it shows it exactly as expected, and sometimes it doesn't show anything at all, it shows `undefined`.

Could this have something to do with my javascript being asynchronous?

Comment: "sometimes", you mean when exactly?

Comment: @SunilBN Exactly the same code, if I press control + F5 it works about 50% of the time

Comment: Will it be able to have running snippet online? 
or can you put the complete code over here. Because I don't see component.oContainer variable in your current code snippet

Comment: @SunilBN I found the answer and posted it underneath if you would like to know. Thank you for your interest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem & answer. SAPUI5 creates and instantiates the component, before creating the container. Depending on how fast the component is created (including the view and controller initializations), this code might already be finished by the time the settings are set.

I also found a way to solve this: instead of settings, I am now using the componentData property, which works like a charm:

```
  var oComponent = sap.ui.getCore().createComponent( {
        url: "resources/components/clientSelector",
        name: "components.clientSelector",
        id: "components.clientSelector",
        componentData: {
          test: "xx"
        }
      });
      var oComponentContainer = new sap.ui.core.ComponentContainer( {
        component: oComponent
      });
```

I can access the oComponent.getComponentData() from the initialization of the first view, and get my test data returned.